# Is Matlab old versions usable with Win 10 on core i3

Tags: matlab

About Matlab (a software very useful for engineerinng, too), Is "Matlab 2008" or "Matlab 2012a" usable on laptop with core "i3" with "Win 10 Home"?

Comment: Ask on Suoer User possibly?

Comment: Matlab is not a software its a operating system ;)

Comment: @joojaa why do you say matlab is an OS ? or is it like "windows is a virus"?

Comment: @SolarMike ot comes with a full compliment of drivers, and driverlike utilities and completely circumvents all system services. As a result matlab is exactly the same no matter what system and no matter what security settings your os has. write a service in any language on windows and you need admin rights, do it in matlab no such problem. In a sense matlab is just a system on a system. Ive known a lot of people who use matlab for everything and dont care what the underlying system is just as long as it runs matlab, ive even had 2 of them say that their preffered os is matlab.

Comment: @joojaa  matlab is completely not an OS.  Just try running MATLAB from a disk that has no actual OS on it -- your machine will not boot.  Period.  Don't go "Humpty Dumpty" on words.

Comment: The whole question of "Is MATLAB useable" can be answered "NO."   get thee to python or R .

Comment: You may not be able to install it without a license key. If you have a license the just ask the Mathaworks.

Answer (score 2):

1. "Windows 2010" is not a Windows version so i'm guessing that you are referring to Windows 10.
2. In general all software that came out since Windows Vista (2007) also runs fine on newer Windows versions like Windows 7, 8 or 10.
3. Since Matlab 2008 requires only a [Pentium 4 with 512MB memory](https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html) it will probably run fine on any current system

Comment: Although the more memory you have, the better, especially if you use some of the add-ons like Simulink.

Comment: tho' minimum requirements and what's required to run at a decent speed are different things.   And I have yet to find a version of MATLAB that doesn't happily crash all on its own regardless of hardware and OS.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I’ve generally found MATLAB (yes all caps is correct) to be reliable on both Windows and on Mac OS. It is hideous expensive. Paying for toolboxes is a drag. I generally use Python with the Anaconda distribution. It’s excellent, but not as polished as MATLAB.

Comment: @EricShain lucky you :-( .  Probably once every week or two MATLAB goes into an internal mystery loop, chewing up 100% of one core, despite zero commands on the console.  It throws graphics errors when the OS (Win7)goes into Sleep.

Comment: Many of you think my question is off topic. In which stackexchange section is suggested to move it?